# Lost access to ubuntu when changing home partition

Tags: mount, gparted, home-directory

I was running out of space on my linux partition so I decided to move the /home to another drive. I had around 16.6 GB free space and would have loved to add it to the existing drive, GParted was not allowing to add it to linux partition as the free space existed before (left side) of the linux partition. So I thought why not make the free space as a separate drive and move /home to it. I was following the tutorial given at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Following the tutorial, I was able to move the home to the new drive. However, I realized that there was only 2 GB free space left. (I should have looked at this before) So I thought to chop off some more space from my Windows drive and add it to the /home partition. So to do this, I needed to make the /home partition as unallocated space so that I could increase the size.

Thus, I wanted to move the /home back from the partition to the linux drive, the way it was before. For this I changed the /etc/fstab entry for the partition I had added back /media/home.

I then ran the command sudo mount -a.

I tried to copy the the old_home back to /home but I think the /home was still pointing to the other partition. So I restarted the system.(This was stupid).

Now, I am unable to login to my account.

How do I get out of this mess?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What's the output to `lsb_release --codename&&uname --kernel-release`?

Answer (score 1):

You can start the computer using a live system (cd, dvd, usb-stick), mount your partitions and order the mess, i.e. copying your files to your intended destination and/or change fstab.